# Positioning an alert box inside a textarea

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I positioned an alert box inside a textarea with the following code :

CSS :

```
#alertBox {
    width: 30%;
    height: 12%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: #0075bf;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#template {
    font-family: Lato Regular;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
/* Medium,Small and Extra Small Devices */

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    #alertBox {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        margin-right: 10%;
    }

    #template {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }
}
```

HTML :

```
   <div class="container">
   <article id="template">
    <form role="form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <h5 for="myOffer">Mon offre</h5>
            <div id="alertBox" class="alert alert-info">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a> Merci de compléter votre offre avant de cliquer sur envoyer
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows=" 13 " id="myOffer "></textarea>
        </fieldset>
    </form>  
    </article>
    </div>
```

However, when I resize the form, the alertbox does not position itself correctly inside the textarea.

Here is how the final results should look like:

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: what do you want. Let use know clearly and remove `width:100%` from `media query` then `margin` will work inside `text area` because you are giving `width:100%` that's why margin is useless.

Comment: When I resize the form(< 992px)  I want the dialog box to take the full width of the textarea like in the image I added. Removing 'width : 100% ' doesn't help either. The dialog box appears above the textbox for smaller screen size.

Comment: so it's simple give `position:relative` to `form-group` class and remove `margin` from `media query` use only `width:100%`

Answer (score 1):

Right way to do this is to set `fieldset` width and position like this and to `textarea` width 100%:

```
fieldset {
    position:relative;
    width: 600px; //for example
}
textarea {
    width:100%;
}
```

Then your arelt box will be absolute to element `<fieldset>`. And when you will resize window at some moment `fieldset` will be e.g 100% and your alert-box will be on the middle of it.

Comment: Thank you. I missed the 'position:relative'.